# Calling active VBA script from another workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I can run this VBA script from the current workbook, but I want to run from another new workbook and get the result on it.

```
Sub ListAllSheets()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim Counter As Integer

Counter = 0

For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    ActiveCell.Offset(Counter, 0).Value = ws.Name
    Counter = Counter + 1
Next ws

End Sub
```

Comment: My workbook name is "Transactions", could you please share your knowledge,  how it looks on the script? Thanks, braX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends a bit on if the workbook is open already, and `ActiveCell` works only when the sheet is `Active` so if you HAVE TO use `ActiveCell`

```
Sub ListAllSheets()
Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = Workbooks("Transactions")
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim Counter As Integer

Counter = 0

For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
    ws.Activate
    Application.ActiveCell.Offset(Counter, 0).Value = ws.Name
    Counter = Counter + 1
Next ws

End Sub
```

This may not do exactly what you want, as neither your question nor your code example were very clear (to me). Try to find another way that does not use `ActiveCell` at all for better results. Maybe something like this:

```
Sub ListAllSheets()
Dim wb1 As Workbook
Set wb1 = Workbooks("Transactions")
Dim ws1 As Worksheet

Dim wb2 As Workbook
Set wb2 = Workbooks("OtherWorkbook")
Dim ws2 as Worksheet
Set ws2 = wb2.Worksheets("Sheet1")

Dim Counter As Integer

Counter = 1

For Each ws1 In wb1.Worksheets
    ws2.Cells(Counter, 1).Value = ws1.Name
    Counter = Counter + 1
Next

End Sub
```

A more reliable way to set a Workbook object is to grab when you open it:

```
Set wb1 = Workbooks.Open("C:\Transactions.xlsx")
```

Comment: Thank you so much braX. It is exactly working as expected.